# Assertion-error on serializer_class django todo app

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a todo API with Django. I am getting an error as ToDoView(view class name) should include serializer_class but I already have it. Here is the code

Router and URL

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()                      
router.register(r'todo', views.ToDOView ,'todo')     

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),       
    path('api/', include(router.urls))               
]
```

View:

```
class ToDOView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class: ToDOserializer
    queryset = ToDo.objects.all()
```

serializers:

```
class ToDOserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model : ToDo
        fields : ('id','title','description','completed')
```

id, title, description and completed are fields of my model

**Error:** *Get this error.*

> AssertionError at /api/todo/ 'ToDOView' should either include a
>   `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()`
>   method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be **`=`**(equal to) instead of **`:`**

```
class ToDOView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class =  ToDOserializer
    queryset = ToDo.objects.all()
```

---

also do the same in `serializer.py`

```
class ToDOserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = ('id','title','description','completed')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It's Solved.